# Remove tab page from a tab control and display the page as a new Window

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am working on a Windows Application using WinForms. I have a tab control(tabMain) and on double clicking the tab page header I need to move its content to a new window and remove the tab from the tabMain.

Here is the code I have tried.

```
 private void tabMain_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        System.Windows.Controls.TabItem tab = (System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)sender;
        var CurrentTab=tabMain.SelectedTab;            
        if (tabMain.TabPages.Count == 0) return;
        tabMain.TabPages.Remove(tabMain.SelectedTab);   
        System.Windows.Window newWindow=new System.Windows.Window();
        newWindow.Content = tab.Content;
        newWindow.Show();        
    }
```

On doing this I am getting an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem'." for the line :

```
 System.Windows.Controls.TabItem tab = (System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)sender;
```

Is there any fix for this. Or any other possible way out?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems in you Code:

1. You have attached your event handler to the TabControl and cast it to TabItem. Because of that you are getting this error.
2. TabItem and Window are the wrong objects. They are both used for a WPF application. For WinForm you must use TabPage and Form
3. You can't set Form.Content . You have to add them individually.

This example should work:

```
private void tabMain_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabMain.TabPages.Count > 0)
    {
        TabPage CurrentTab = tabMain.SelectedTab;
        tabMain.TabPages.Remove(CurrentTab);
        Form newWindow = new Form();

        foreach (Control ctrl in CurrentTab.Controls)
        {
            newWindow.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }

        newWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you will need a different method to loop through the controls, as calling Controls.Add there will remove the control from the tab page which will in turn stop the foreach loop iterating (only ever copying 1 control). Something like while(CurrentTab.Controls.Count > 0) { newWindow.Controls.Add(CurrentTab.Controls[0]; }